# How to get the weight for a stored image in Delphi 2009?

Tags: database, image, delphi, delphi-2009

I have images stored in my database, when fetching these images I wish to know what the weight (20KB,90KB,etc.) per image is. How do I get this info? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Which Database are using?
2. What is the type of the field?

Comment: Sorry, my DB is MySQL and the field is BLOB type. So, Aldo's answer works fine. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a BLOB field then you can use the following

```
    SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(column) FROM table t;
```

but it would be really nice if we knew your dbms

Edit: you can also try the following approach (I won't supply code since I dont have delphi now)

but the idea is :

load the image into a TMemoryStream then get the size using TMemoryStream.Size

Answer (score 0):

Delphi stores images in databases using the TGraphicField which normally converts your images to a BMP blob stream before storing them.

So saving your images to a BMP file should give you a good indication on the size in your DB.

Note however that some database systems can compress the underlying blobs, and some TGraphic plugins can deliver other image formats.

So like [RRUZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91299/rruz) already commented: knowing the type of database system and image helps a lot.

--jeroen